# is MongoDB GridFS good solution for storing large amount of files (pdf, xls, doc, dwg etc)?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs, nosql

Currently, we are storing some files for our ERP system in the file system but it's a cumbersome to build a folder structure and query them. There are 10s of 1000s of files. All ERP modules are using mysql.

I'm hoping that a 'bucket' type of storage with some metadata such as GridFs would make things easier. For example:

```
    {"module" : "quotation", "id" : 57894, "file" : "acme_inc_rfq.pdf"}
    {"module" : "quotation", "id" : 57894, "file" : "machine_dwg.dwg"}
    {"module" : "quotation", "id" : 57894, "file" : "data_sheet.xls"}
    {"module" : "po", "id" : 74896, "file" : "our_rfq.xls"}
```

so I can query module=quotation where id=57894 and get a list of these 3 files, and display links and other operations on them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GridFS is perfectly suitable for storing large files.  Essentially, MongoDB even automatically generates `ObjectId` fields for new documents, include GridFS files.  You'd have to handle any sort of virtual folder structure, one which is presented on your application, in a separate collection.

See [MongoDB GridFS](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS) for more information.